# JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 Fixed Persistent Header/Footer

Tags: jquery-mobile, external, persistent

I want to implement External Fixed Persistent Header/Footer in my hybrid APP.

My APP has:

- let's say three initial "pages" with External Fixed Persistent Header but **no Footer at all**;
- at that third "page" I have a link to a series of "pages" with
  External Fixed Persistent Header, but now, **they have also a External Fixed Persistent Footer**.

I'm trying this schema without success. That is, fixed persistent header looks great, but the addition of persistent footer (from the fourth screen) is not working at all.

Is it possible or I must take a different design approach?

Best regards.

Comment: apply the JQM style `ui-screen-hidden` to the footer for the pages where you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks for your time **deblocker**. Going further with your explanation, must I understand that is not possible to have an external header-footer in some pages an another external header-footer in others? Only the same shown and hidden, isn't it?

Comment: IMHO, i believe you are talking about how to set visibility and/or different *content* to the footer, depending from the page, So, by having *a lot of pages*, i would instantiate an external footer and - using that - i would set dynamically the content inside. Just my two cents.